# Converting DWG, DWF, DWFX to 3ds and other

Tags: silverlight, 3d, visualization, 3ds, dwg

I want to show 3D models for DWG/DWF/DWFX files into web-browser.
My way is use Silverlight and 3D-engies to render it (for example, [this](http://balder.codeplex.com/) or [this](http://kit3d.codeplex.com/)). But it allow to render 3ds format, but not DWG/DWF/DWFX .

My idea is convert DWG/DWF/DWFX to 3ds on a server side and transfer 3ds to the client. But I can't find any tools for DWG/DWF/DWFX conversion.

Is there possible to convert DWG/DWF/DWFX files into 3ds or other 3D-formats?

Thank you!

Comment: May be any other options to display dwfx content in browser?